# Magento SSL error on checkout

Tags: magento, ssl

Im getting the following error on my checkout page

Your connection to www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the look of the page.
The connection uses TLS 1.0.
The connection is encrypted using RC4_128, with SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

When I look at console I see the following error

The page at 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/firecheckout/' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at 'http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/advancedsearch/result/': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

When I flush the cache, sometimes it clears it and sometimes it doesn't, if I set /advancedsearch/result/ it always load https:// then it throws another warning

Im a little stuck at the moment can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when you include any resource without https://

so simply see page source view(Ctrl+U) and find CSS,JS,Image which is unsecure link(http) and change this to secure link(https)

Comment: Yes I know this its loading the search form with an action of http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/advancedsearch/result/ rather than https://